# Standard Haskell development environment as of 2014

Tags: haskell, emacs

This question might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504/what-are-my-ide-editor-choices-for-haskell , but the answers couldn't help me a lot.

Recently I am trying to write software with Haskell. I am not a newbie; I learned Haskell ten years ago and have created some programs with the standard development environment at that time, Emacs and Haskell-mode.

Since then, many things have changed. Common tools have become distributed as Haskell Platform, Sublime Text became one of the most common editors for developers, Scion and ghc-mod appeared, and Haskell.org got much more sophisticated interface than even before.

But more surprising thing is, some of them have already become stale! [Scion](https://github.com/nominolo/scion) haven't been maintained anymore and I couldn't install it because of [this error](https://code.google.com/p/scion-lib/issues/detail?id=54). But even on that situation [Haskell.org](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs) doesn't mention anything. It seems as if using Emacs itself is outdated.

So what is the most standard and recommended way to write Haskell programs as of 2014?

Comment: I will second your vote that the linked question was unhelpful. At one point I put effort into learning Leksah, but I never got it working reasonably well. Sadly, I'm still using a side-by-side vanilla text editor and terminal.

Comment: I wouldn't call Emacs has become outdated. Infact ghc-mod and haskell-mode is quite active.

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3 with SublimeHaskell and SublimeLinter-hlint, and I haven't had many problems other than getting those configured and all the optional dependencies installed. I have real time compilation and linting, and I use a terminal to run everything.

Comment: @bheklilr I was excited about this until I realized it's 70USD.

Comment: @Eric You can use it for free indefinitely if you don't mind an occasional popup asking you to support the developer.  I just found that I was getting better than a 1% productivity increase from the editor, particularly with Python and Java compared to Eclipse-based IDEs, which meant that I was getting a good ROI.  It isn't really that expensive compared to other IDEs, most of which are suited for one family of programming languages.  Visual Studio starts off at 1200$/year, WingIDE is about 100$ for a noncommercial license, FPComplete is 100$/year.  Sublime is a relatively cheap option.